# Has a dmath environment (breqn package) a maximum size?

Tags: math-mode, landscape, breqn

I have the problem, that I need some quite long formulas and therefore I use `breqn`. Up till now, there was no problem doing so. But now I have a formula that seems to be too long for `breqn`. I get some error messages like

```
! Extra \else.
\eq@trial@b ...e }\eq@trial@succeed \fi \fi \else 
  \eq@trial@save \EQ@last@tr...
l.55 \end{dmath}
```

These messages are coming several times in the log. The output in the PDF file is correct, but the messages are not pretty. Also I will have to set some even longer formulas and then the output will be even worse.

So my question: Why are there these messages and what can I do against them?

PS: A minimal example. If you disable the `landscape` environment you will see the error:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{dmath}
\stackrel{(4)}{y}_1 = -b_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 \,x_6^2-c_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5
\,x_6^2+2\,c_1\,v_1\,\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\sin x_5 \,x_6-2\,c_1\,\dot v_1 \,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 
\,x_6+c_1\,d_3\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 \,x_6+c_1\,d_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 \,x_6-2\,b_1\,v_1\,
\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\cos x_5 \,x_6+2\,b_1\,\dot v_1 \,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 \,x_6-b_1\,d_3\,v_1\,\cos x_3 
\,\cos x_5 \,x_6-b_1\,d_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 \,x_6-b_1\,c_2\,{v_1}^{2}\,\sin x_3 \,\sin^2 x_5 -
a_3\,c_1\,v_1\,\cos^2 x_3 \,\sin^2 x_5 -c_1\,c_2\,v_1^2\,\sin x_3 \,\cos x_5 \,\sin x_5 b_1\,b_2\,v_1^2\,\sin x_3 \,\cos x_5 \,\sin x_5 +a_3\,b_1\,v_1\,\cos^2 x_3 \,\cos x_5 \,\sin x_5 -
b_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,x_4^2\,\sin x_5 -2\,b_1\,\dot v_1 \,\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\sin x_5 +b_1\,d_2\,v_1\,
\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\sin x_5 +b_1\,d_1\,v_1\,\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\sin x_5 -a_1\,b_1\,v_1\,\sin^2 x_3 \,\sin 
x_5 -a_2\,b_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_3 \,\sin x_5 -b_3\,c_1\,v_1\,v_2\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 +b_1\,
\ddot v_1  \,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 -b_1\,d_1\,\dot v_1 \,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_5 +b_1\,d_1^2\,v_1\,\cos x_3 
\,\sin x_5 -b_2\,c_1\,v_1^2\,\sin x_3 \,\cos^2 x_5 -c_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,x_4^2\,\cos x_5 -2\,c_1\,
\dot v_1 \,\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\cos x_5 +c_1\,d_2\,v_1\,\sin x_3 \,x_4\,\cos x_5 +c_1\,d_1\,v_1\,\sin x_3 
\,x_4\,\cos x_5 -a_1\,c_1\,v_1\,\sin^2 x_3 \,\cos x_5 -a_2\,c_1\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\sin x_3 \,\cos x_5 
+b_1\,b_3\,v_1\,v_2\,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 +c_1\,\ddot v_1  \,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 -c_1\,d_1\,\dot v_1 
\,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 +c_1\,d_1^2\,v_1\,\cos x_3 \,\cos x_5 -d_1^3\,x_2
\end{dmath}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around - leaving this as-is in the example causes a problem.

Comment: OK, throw the package out and the two lines. Then I get some errors (texlive 2011)

Comment: do you need the equation number? If not use simply `$...$` instead of `dmath`

Comment: Commenting out the `landscape` environment, I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\eq@dense@enough@b ...m@b <\dim@c \true@true@true 
                                                  \else \false@true@false \fi 
l.25 \end{dmath}`

Comment: @Herbert: $..$ does not break the equation, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Yes, that's part of the error message I get.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You're right. Re-ordering the package loading under TeX Live 2009 fixes the problem. But under TeX Live 2011, not so much.

Comment: @Christian Wolf: See [mathmode](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/) at page 11 section *Linebreak*

Comment: Adding `\makeatletter \def\true@true@true{\fi\fi\iftrue\iftrue\iftrue} \makeatother` after loading `breqn` package fixes it... yes?

Comment: @Werner: Now I get another message about a too large dimension.

Comment: I have also seen that breqn seems not to be able to break over the page. Is there no way to do so? Otherwise the formular will neiger go on the page on landscape nor on portrait mode.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Any errors with the addition of `\true@true@true`?

Comment: @Marco: (and Herbert) I do not need the eq numbers for now. If I use $...$ he really breaks the lines but the right margin of the paper is more or less useless. He writes over the paper boundary. Any way to get it shorter?

Comment: I believe that the problem is that **breqn** isn't able to find proper places where to break. If I set 1.82cm margins on a5paper, there's no error; the error begins to show with 1.83cm margins.

Comment: @egreg: In `breqn` (2009/08/07 v0.98a), searching for `\true@true@true`, there's one use, but no definition. Perhaps, changing the margins re-aligns the equation and doesn't require `\true@true@true`.

Comment: @Werner: indeed, your suggestions works for me. No "too large dimension error". You might turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: If breqn is not able to break the page, I will have to look for another way of typesetting the formulas. So any suggestions?

Comment: @Werner: adding the definition of `\true@true@true` makes the code compile without any errors in my system.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the definition

```
\makeatletter
\def\true@true@true{\fi\fi\iftrue\iftrue\iftrue}
\makeatother
```

corrects the error under TeX Live 2011.

Loading the [`pdflscape` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) **before** the [`breqn` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) seems to solves the problem under TeX Live 2009 (tested on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com)).